# Custom Authentication scheme IOptionsMonitor not working

Tags: authentication, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-authorization

I have set up an authentication scheme. I am trying to pass on options from the startup class.

In my start up I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(TokenAuthentication.SchemeName)
.AddScheme<TokenAuthenticationOptions, TokenAuthentication>
                    (TokenAuthentication.SchemeName, o => {
                        o.AuthQueryKey = "jwt";
                    });
```

In my scheme class I have the following constructor:

```
    public TokenAuthentication(IOptionsMonitor<TokenAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, 
                                UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, LoginManager loginManager) 
                                    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        this.options = options;
        this.loginManager = loginManager;
    }
```

Inside the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` I am trying to access the options like this:

```
var options = this.options.CurrentValue;
if (options.AuthQueryKey == null) // always null
```

On debugger I found that the constructor runs first, then the `o.AuthQueryKey = "jwt"` and finally the `HandleAuthenticateAsync`. Why doesn't `AuthQueryKey` get the value "jwt"?

The reason I need to use options is since I am reusing the authentication in two projects with different attributes. My next resort is to use another singleton for options, but why isn't this lamda function setting the value?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options, I need to set the options  with the `Configure` function.

```
services.Configure<TokenAuthenticationOptions>(o => {
    o.AuthQueryKey = "jwt";
});
```

It is still odd though that I can't figure out what the lamda inside the `AddScheme` function is even meant for.